# The italic fonts on team are hard to read in non capital letters

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams, accessibility

[image]

The font used for monospace italics on teams (when composing a post in markdown mode) are a little hard to read. It might be my dyslexia but, the r, f and s are... indistinct and significantly harder to read than the fonts used elsewhere

Regular Monospace looks fine

[image]

I'm on Windows 10, and running [Vivaldi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivaldi_%28web_browser%29) 3.8 (while unsupported, it's another [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine))/Chrome based browser)

Comment: I would say even the small L (it looks like an e). Do they look normal in non-italic text though?

Comment: example added. It looks fine

Comment: I just updated windows yesterday - so its possible. I don't post on teams that often so I don't know how recent this change could have happened from my point of view.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one that finds it illegible.

Comment: OT: I'm afraid you used "jumpS" instead of "jumpED" only one time.

Comment: Alas, I'm not an acolyte of Her Lady Mavis Beacon, Patron Saint of Typing :D

Comment: In Russian (and possibly other languages), the word for "italic font" is "cursive", while in English, "cursive" means "handwritten". Maybe there was a misunderstanding somewhere, leading designers to put handwritten letters into the italic font.

Comment: @anatolyg cursive means _joined_ writing, not handwritten

Comment: @anatolyg It is true that handwriting is (or was?) preferably done with cursive, but I think cursive means the same as you describe for Russian.

Comment: It's not just Teams, it's anywhere the new editor is.  So MSE/MSO answers also have it.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that later and posted it to the teams font post.

Comment: It's 2021. It's time to bring cursive back. Recursive, if you will.  >Ducking thrown objects<

Comment: Whose idea was to have a cursive monospace font as a default option in Windows??? I 100% guarantee you that whoever made that decision isn't a programmer.

Comment: @Kit - here's your coat... and your hat. The exit is ➡  

Comment: @Kit I wonder why meta seems to attract lovers of bad puns?  They seem much more prevalent here than on the main site.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand why they didn't just use the user's `monospace` font...

Comment: Additional "non-cursive" characters are now also being added to the font: [Issue 468](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/issues/468#issuecomment-854196781)

Answer (score 17):

Just tested, and this is because of the new Cascadia Fonts that were released 2 days ago: [Cascadia Code 2105.24](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases/tag/v2105.24). I'm using Ubuntu, however, I do have the Cascadia Code fonts installed. As, however, I'm not on Windows there's no automatic update process for it (if I recall correctly, Windows Terminal ships the Cascadia Code Fonts to Windows, though there are likely others) so I wasn't seeing what the OP was. I just installed the Italic Fonts for Cascadia Code and voila!

[image: here are your cursive characters]

This explains the *why*; I don't have an answer for how to stop it (for me personally, I disabled the Italic Fonts in Kubuntu's Font Manager). It should probably be a feature request on [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com) to not use the italic font style; if that is even possible.

*Edit: There is also an [Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/issues/468) open on the Cascadia Code GitHub asking for version of the font to exist without these "cursive" characters for the italics characters.*

---

Update: The next release of Cascadia Code will now be providing "non-cursive" characters by default in the italic style. The current "cursive" characters will still be available, however, you will need to enable OpenType in the software you are using. [Issue 468](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/issues/468#issuecomment-854196781)

Comment: I happen to be a mod there. . There's an ongoing post for the new font changed and I will post there

Comment: Interestingly - this dosen't affect the 'classic' editor - only the teams and alpha one

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It seems to me that Cascadia implemented **real** _italic_ characters and you are looking for  _slanted_ ones. I cannot check now, but possibly Cascadia supports also a slanted style.

Comment: I suspect you can choose to only install the font without the italics file, @gboffi , however, I suspect the problem is that an app Journeyman Geek uses, such as Windows Terminal (WT), has shipped the entire font pack to them *including* the new *italics* style (coined "Cascadia Curve"). This [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/10231) on the Windows Terminal GitHub appears to imply this is the case. I haven't turned on my Windows Laptop in the last couple of days, but I suspect a "fix" would be to remove the fonts, but I also *suspect* WT will ship them over again.

Comment: I do use windows terminal.  Oh, this is turning into a really fun issue report.

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to use [Fontconfig](https://www.fontconfig.org/), in this thread (["Forcing Artificial Italics on Fonts That *DO* Have One Available?"](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/fontconfig/2008-August/002999.html)) they propose a solution to ignore the official italic version of a font and serve instead an artificially slanted face to the user.

I don't know if a similar trick is possible outside of a Fontconfig-managed font environment.

<sub>Caveat emptor: I haven't tested the proposed solution because: ① I'm pretty happy reading cursive italic and ② I trust [the solution's proponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Packard).</sub>